# How does RDS replicate a Postgres database through multiple availability zones

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is there some kind of native Postgres tool they use, or is it a custom one? Are the replicas always in sync or do they drift apart from time to time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Multi-AZ RDS replication is synchronous. And since AWS like to be in full control of their software, it’s most likely a customised replication (but I couldn’t tell you for sure).